# Create a branch on a remote repository with pygit2

Tags: python, git, pygit2

I am using pygit2 to create a branch on a remote repository.
If it was in a local repository i would've used :

```
repo=pygit2.Repository(repo_url)                                                  
repo.create_branch('branch1', repo.head.get_object(), force=False)
```

But when i give the function Repository a remote url (not a path) it doesn't work, is there a solution ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only create remote branches by `push`ing.

Comment: and how can i do it ?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create your branch locally and then push it to the remote.
Once its pushed you can add remote with the branch name to track it locally (required on older git versions prior to 1.9).

The push command is **[here](http://www.pygit2.org/remotes.html?highlight=push#pygit2.Remote.push)**.

---

```sh
git push --set-upstream <remote> <branch>
```

Comment: How do you push a branch that isn't the currently checked out branch?

Comment: git push <branch name> - it will create a new branch on the remote `git push --set-upstream <remote> <branch>`